# php pregsplit regex for parenthesis

Tags: php, preg-split

I have string like this:

> (17:1)(1:0)(5:0)

How can I get to array like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => 17:1 
[1] => 1:0
[2] => 5:0
)
```

Comment: `$result = explode(')(', trim($str, '()'));`

Comment: Yes, `preg_split` is one option. Any attempts or research yet? (Really helps to avoid redundant answers and DVs to mention both right away.)

Comment: Go to [regexr](http://regexr.com) and try it out!

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte thanks for your solution

Comment: Now, you must to find the way to do it with `preg_split` (or `preg_match_all`). Read a regex tutorial, the patterns to do that are not difficult.

Comment: I disagree with the vote to close on this question - it's *not* too broad, answers are clearly not too long for this format (see the comment above with a one line answer). The problem is that the OP hasn't tried anything himself, and we're punishing him for it. Sometimes this happens on StackOverflow and can be useful for people in future, so let it be?

Comment: @Robbie Averill thanks for your thoughts. I should say to I did try really a lot of things but I didn't write here, for example like this: preg_split("/\((.*)\)+/", $mystring); and like this: preg_split("/[^\(](.*)[^\)]+/", $mystring); .. etc..and I did find this working solution: preg_split("/\)/", str_replace("(","",substr($mystring,0,-1))); But this way some a long solution. The problem is my English is not good as you so explore and learn a little difficult for me :s

Answer (score 1):

My solution (preg_split):

```
$result = preg_split("/\)/", str_replace("(","",substr($mystring,0,-1)));
```

Thanks to  Casimir et Hippolyte for explode example:

```
$result = explode(')(', trim($str, '()'));
```

Comment: The suggested answer is better I think, the substring use is a bit hacky

Comment: I agree suggested answer is better and I used suggested answer code. I just want write here, how can do this with preg_split. I did write as a answer and if I did wrong moderator can delete my post.

Comment: Nope, +1 for answering yourself :-)